# AFNetworking POST request with array of JSON objects

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

So I'm trying to do a post request with an array of JSON parameters sent to a server, here's the code for that

```
    for(USER_ACTIONS *ua in [USER_ACTIONS listRegisterdActions]){
        //Create a single JSON object here
         [array addObject:jsonString];
     }
     NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",array.count ?      

     NSData* data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     parameters[@"data"] = data;

     [self POST:@"?cmd=log" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

     }];
```

This works with a single JSON object, but once there are more of them I get the following exception

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'

It's out of the question to do this with a multiple post requests so I need a way to do this with one, my search results on this have not gotten any clear results on how to do this with AFNetworking 2.x so I'd appreciate some pointers on where to go with this.

Answer (score 2):

AFNetworking can automatically change paramter in NSDictionary to JSON.

change your manager's property `requestSerializer` to `AFJSONRequestSerializer` the default value is `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`

`AFJSONRequestSerializer` is a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` that encodes parameters as JSON using `NSJSONSerialization`, setting the `Content-Type` of the encoded request to `application/json`.

Comment: okay, but how do I send multiple dictionaries with only one request like that?

Comment: @Oz0234 merge your dictionaries into one

Comment: won't that just replace the values previously added for each key? Also the server fails to read the parameters correctly if I pass them inside a NSDictionary

Comment: @Oz0234 oh then you should use a array as paramter

Comment: the server still can't read the parameters of the request like that

Comment: It insists that the parameters sent to the log service are null

Answer (score 0):

For some reason just using the AFHTTPSessionManager Post function with the constructingBodyWithBlock parameter actually works for some reason. No idea why this is needed because there isn't actually anything in that block, if anyone could tell me why it would be nice.

```
    [self POST:@"?cmd=log"  parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //For some reason the request won't work unless this block is included in the function as well, even though nothing is actually done in it
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        //Success code here
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    }];
```